# Anchor links to wrong page location only once

Tags: html, css, anchor, href

I am coding a personal portfolio website, and my nav links to different divs down the page. When the page first opens, one of my nav items links too far down the div, but every other time, it works.

Here is a rough example of the problem; I think the problem is in the grey box (which in the real website is a container for thumbnails) and the javaScript.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main3.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/script3.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">

            <nav>
                <a id="nav_design" href="#design_portfolio_cover"> DESIGN </a> 
                <a id="nav_illustration" href="#illustration_portfolio_cover"> ILLUSTRATION </a> 
            </nav>
            <section id="design_portfolio">
                <div id="design_portfolio_cover">
                    <h2>Design--working</h2>
                </div>  
                <section id="design_portfolio_body">
                    <section id="project-d2" class="project">                           
                    </section>  
                    <section id="project-d3" class="project">                           
                    </section>                          
                    <section id="project-d4" class="project">
                        <div id="portfolio_images-d4" class="portfolio_images">
                            <div id="thumbnails-d4" class="thumbnails">     
                            </div> 
                        </div>  
                    </section>  
                </section>   
            </section>
            <section id="illustration_portfolio">
                <div id="illustration_portfolio_cover">
                            <h2>Illustration--not working</h2>
                </div>  
            </section>

            <div id="footer_grey" class="fullscreen_grey"></div> 

        </div><!--    end wrapper -->
    </body>
</html>
```

and the CSS...

```
*{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; 
    border: 0px;
}

#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

nav{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 16px 0px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    position: fixed;
}

#design_portfolio_cover{
    padding: 250px 0px;
    background-color: #e2b42b;
    height: 367px;
    width: 100%;
}
#illustration_portfolio_cover{
    padding: 250px 0px;
    background-color: #e2b42b;
    height: 367px;
    width: 100%;
}
#design_portfolio_body{
    width: 100%;
}

.thumbnails{
    width: 805px;
    height: 140px;
    background-color: gray;
}

/* JS CLASSES */

.thumbnails_fixed{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.thumbnails_final{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

/* END JS CLASSES */

#footer_grey{
    width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    float: none;
}
```

and, finally, the JavaScript

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    let project = $('#project-d4').offset().top;
    let project2 = $('#illustration_portfolio').offset().top;
    if (scroll >= project2){
        $('#thumbnails-d4').removeClass('thumbnails_fixed');
        $('#thumbnails-d4').addClass('thumbnails_final');
    }
    if (scroll < project2 && scroll > project){
        $('#thumbnails-d4').addClass('thumbnails_fixed');
        $('#thumbnails-d4').removeClass('thumbnails_final');
    }
});
```

*I hope this isn't too much code...whenever I tried to delete the empty elements, the problem went away.*

The first time I click on #nav_illustration, it pops down a bit past the #illustration_portfolio_cover. Every other time, it goes directly to the top of it like it should. All the other links work just fine the first time. I just can't figure out why it doesn't work the first time. Any thoughts?

Comment: Most often things like this happen, when the page layout is not fully build already at the time you follow such a link - for example because images are still loading. Hard to tell if that’s the issue with just those snippets only though - please provide a [mcve].

Comment: As first comment mentioned, most likely due to page not fully loaded and images are most likely the cause. There is a way to work around this https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/ this method can be applied to images. In modern sites, image dimensions can be defined and the space for the image is preserved. So that no matter when you click an internal link, it always goes to the right place

Comment: I checked out the link from @Huangism (thanks!) and tried several of the fixes. However, it either didn't work or made the div disappear altogether. I did go ahead and put in the full example above, though, and in making it minimal, found that the problem seems to be in the JavaScript/CSS area, probably in that "thumbnails" div.

Comment: The problem is you are changing the position of thumbnails-d4 to absolute which takes it out of the normal content flow and when you do that, you will lose 140px in height since that's how tall it is. When you lose that height, your scroll goes too low. I am not sure how your project comes together so I don't know how you want to fix this, but that's the issue.

Comment: @Huangism, Thanks so much! I actually just figured that out, and I went ahead and put absolute positioning on all the thumbnails from the beginning, so it just switches between absolute and fixed. Works like a charm! I'd mark your answer as accepted if I could figure out how. :)

Comment: @Nina I added an answer, glad you were able to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are changing the position of thumbnails-d4 to absolute which takes it out of the normal content flow and when you do that, you will lose 140px in height since that's how tall it is. When you lose that height, your scroll goes too low. I am not sure how your project comes together so I don't know how you want to fix this, but that's the issue.

You could position the thumbs absolute from the start if that fits your needs or you will need a placeholder to keep that space or minus 140 from your scrolled position.